# pw hash compare nodejs

Tags: node.js, hash, bcrypt

I am trying to compare password for my login system using bcrypt module, however it seems to not work. As soon as I submit the data into the form, I get {"message":"Internal Server Error"} (which I have defined). What I'm doing wrong?

Here is auth-controller.js:

```
var mysqlConnection = require ('../config');
const bcrypt = require ('bcrypt');

module.exports.auth = async function (req, res) { 
  var password = req.body.password
  var email = req.body.email
  console.log(email, password);

let pwComparison

try {
  //Check the password
  pwComparison = await pwCompare(password)

  //Compare the hashed password
  password = await bcrypt.compare(password,results)

} catch (e) {
  return res.status(500).json({message: 'Internal Server Error'})
}

if (pwComparison) {
  res.redirect('/')
}

async function pwCompare(password) {

  let query = `SELECT password FROM users where password = ${password}`

  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query(query, function(error,results) {
      if (error) {
        return reject (error)
      }

      return resolve(results)
    })
  })
}}
```

Comment: After you catch the error, put there `console.log(e)` so it will tell you what went wrong. Then either fix it, or put it here if you dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Additionally, you should neither log passwords, nor use template strings to build your SQL statements.  Both represent non-trivial security holes.  The former can be fixed by simply not doing it; the latter can be fixed by using parameterized queries (which mysql supports).

Comment: Managed to consolelog the error, here's what it throws out: "Error: data and hash arguments required"

Answer (score 0):

You should not be querying for the password, you should be querying for the user.  The password in your DB is presumably encrypted, so the value that's coming from the client will never match.  I'm guessing that you're trying to compare a null to a string, which is probably where your error is coming from.  It's helpful for you to log the error, though, so you'll know for sure.

Try this:

```
module.exports.auth = async function (req, res) { 
  const password = req.body.password
  const email = req.body.email
  console.log(email);

let user = null;
let isMatch = false;

try {
  //Check the password
  user = await getUserByEmail(email)

  //Compare the hashed password
  isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

} catch (e) {
  return res.status(500).json({message: 'Internal Server Error'})
}

if (isMatch) {
  req.user = user;
  res.redirect('/');
}

async function getUserByEmail(email) {

  let query = "SELECT password FROM users where email = ? LIMIT 1";

  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query(query, [email], function(error,results) {
      if (error) {
        return reject (error)
      }
      if (results.length == 1) 
         return resolve(results[0])
      else
         return resolve(null)
    });
  })
}}
```

Update based on your comments.

Ok, my miss on the query; you were returning an array of users that match the query, which means just an array of one.  In any case, you need to get the actual user from that array.

I've updated the query to limit the search to a single user (small perf bonus, even if you only have unique email addresses), and also your query callback to return the single returned row rather than the array.  One could argue that not finding a user should be a `reject()` instead of a null result, I leave that decision to you.

Comment: Tried but it's not working, still throwing Internal server error. If I put a console.log(e) after I catch the error, nothing logs on the console

Comment: console.log(password,user.password) passes these values:    alex9624 undefined

Comment: @Danielcraig Then either your query is wrong (did you update as I recommended?) or the DB user you looked up doesn't have a password set.

Comment: yep I have updated as you recommended, and the user I am looking for has the password set, which is hashed.

Comment: @Danielcraig Something is wrong with your query, the data you're expecting or the data as it is in the DB.  If you `console.log(user)` what do you get?  For that matter, if in your mysql callback what do you get when you `console.log(results)`

Comment: If I console.log(user) I receive back "[ RowDataPacket {
    password:
     '$2b$10$8aQGZys3nCqtMJRazXPJs.u/hD2GpVEfX3pJIuG03bCw6VJAvris6' } ]" so the value passed is right. EDIT: I changed await bcrypt.compare(password,user) and now it says "Error: data and hash must be strings"

Comment: @Danielcraig Ok, I see the problem now.  Please note my updated code and explanation.

Comment: Hi. Tried the updated version, however I am still getting "data and hash must be strings".

Comment: What's the updated console look like after the change I recommended?

Comment: Same as before, throws out "[ RowDataPacket { password: '$2b$10$8aQGZys3nCqtMJRazXPJs.u/hD2GpVEfX3pJIuG03bCw6VJAvris6' } ]"

Comment: Oh... Check again, I forgot one of the changes I'd meant to make

Comment: ok, modified and seems to not give back any error, but on form send it loads forever, it's not sending back to /